# Customize eclipse taskbar

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I use a lot of eclipse shortcuts, but for some tasks there arnt any convenient ones. For example I frequently look at the subversion history for java files.

I see these icons next to the right-click menu items that I assume I should be able to place on the eclipse taskbar so that I can save a couple of mouse clicks. But I havnt been able to figure out how to do that yet.

I am talking about the icon next to RightClick-Team-Show History once you install the subclipse plugin. I would like this icon to be on my taskbar so I can just do a single click and look at the history.

Any suggestions?

Other tips on customizing eclipse for java development are also welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at my answer for similar question: [How to add undo / redo buttons to toolbar in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819846/how-to-add-undo-redo-buttons-to-toolbar-in-eclipse)

It is possible to do the same for Show History command. Differences are: 1) you need to declare dependency on `org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui` plugin, and command ID you are looking for is `org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui.showresourceinhistoryaction`. You may want to include custom icon to avoid having long "Show History" button on your toolbar.

**Update:** Here is downloadable plugin for you: [showsvnhistory_1.0.0.jar](http://www.foglyn.com/misc/showsvnhistory_1.0.0.jar)

Comment: Yes... Eclipse is too powerful sometimes, it's very easy to get lost :( I still don't understand all related magic ... fortunately, contributing new action to toolbar is easy, once there is command defined for it.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I will be trying this out later in the evening.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of to "customize" the Eclipse taskbar is via Window -> Customize Perspective. Oddly enough, the "Commands" tab has some influence on the toolbar.

But the developer of whatever component you want to use must have enabled the commmand and (at least for me), SVN doesn't offer a history button.

Maybe some XML hacking is more helpful here?