# Adding "open file" button to eclipse toolbar

Tags: eclipse, customization, toolbar

I know you can add new buttons to the eclipse toolbar by writing a custom plugin but just how would i go about adding a simple "open file" button like most editors have?

I guess I can use this as a template to do what i want, but what's the commandId for the "open file dialog":

[How to add undo / redo buttons to toolbar in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819846/how-to-add-undo-redo-buttons-to-toolbar-in-eclipse)

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a toolbar button which mimics the behaviour of the menu File->Open File..., then you are searching for the command id

```
org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.openLocalFile
```

which you would want to use instead of the command ids for the undo/redo in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a specific commandId for open file dialog that you can use in the toolbar or menu. You would have to create a class that implements the `IHandler` interface and use something like the `JFileChooser` to handle the selection of the file.